# Google Maps API Autocomplete search box

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I have followed Google Dev's tutorial on how to add a location search box with auto complete: [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete?utm_source=welovemapsdevelopers&utm_campaign=mdr-gdl)

But i cant seem to get it working. The box is displayed and i can type, but the autocomplete function does not work as intended and nothing happens when i type and hit return.

HTML:

```
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Location..."> <!-- Location Search Box -->
        <div id="map-canvas"></div> 
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
tidy_maps.initialize = function() {
// Declare the map and its options
var myOptions = {
    center: ireland,
    zoom: 7,
    panControl: false,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
    },

    streetViewControl: false,
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        myOptions);

// Set default bounds for search box - biased towards Ireland
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(55.51150, -10.22827),
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.43514, -5.43823));

// Add Search Box to Map space
var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

var options = {
    bounds: defaultBounds
};

// Create Autocomplete for Search
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

Comment: and where do you create the autocomplete?

Comment: sorry i left out that line in my post (autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

Comment: did you load the places-library?

Comment: yeah i have it included in the <head> with all the other libraries: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>

Comment: Actually, There seems to be problem with my libraries clashing. I also have a Drawing library and when i take it out, the autocomplete works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: I originally had 2 separate libraries trying to load:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing"></script>
```

But changed it to load both in 1:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,drawing"></script>
```